# Random Set fixed size in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, set

I'm working on getting random array from a .json file in React. I'm using it to make cards, and want the cards to be exactly 16 cards where each number shows twice.
I'm using a `Set` to keep it unique, then making an array, but can't figure out how to trigger the loop to end once the Set size is 8.
As of now, I have it hard-coded as eight, but if there's a duplicate, the Set ends up too small, which I understand why. It seems the loop doesn't have access to the Set size, but I don't know how to make that happen. I tried `this.state.practiceCards.size < 8` but it didn't work.

How do I get the loop to end?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
      this.state = {
        cards,
        practiceCards: new Set(),
        practiceCardsArray: [],
      }
      this.addPracticeCard = this.addPracticeCard.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addPracticeCard();
  }

  addPracticeCard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
      this.setState(state => ({
          practiceCards: state.practiceCards.add(cards[randIndex]),
          practiceCardsArray: [...state.practiceCards, ...state.practiceCards]
      }))
    }
  }
```

Comment: how about waiting until the set has the correct number of cards first then call setState. keep track of the set in the function locally to test its size

Comment: The code you provided is not enough, can you please what do you have in the constructor?

Comment: @SaifMasadeh, thanks I edited the question to include the constructor code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.generatePracticeCards();
  }

  generatePracticeCards() {
    for (let i = 0; this.state.practiceCards.size < 8; i++){
      this.addRandomCard();
    }
  }

  addRandomCard() {
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    this.setState({ practiceCards: this.state.practiceCards.add(cards[randIndex]) })
  }
```